# Use lapply on a subset of list elements and return list of same length as original in R

Tags: regex, r, plyr, lapply

I want to apply a regex operation to a subset of list elements (which are character strings) using lapply and return a list of same length as the original. The list elements are long strings (derived from reading in long text files and collapsing paragraphs into a single string). The regex operation is valid only for the subset of list elements/strings. I want the non-subsetted list elements (character strings) to be returned in their original state.

The regex operation is `str_extract` from the `stringr` package, i.e. I want to extract a substring from a longer string. I subset the list elements based on a regex pattern in the filename.

An example with simplified data:

```
library(stringr)
texts <- as.list(c("abcdefghijkl", "mnopqrstuvwxyz", "ghijklmnopqrs", "uvwxyzabcdef"))
filenames <- c("AB1997R.txt", "BG2000S.txt", "MN1999R.txt", "DC1997S.txt")
names(texts) <- filenames
regexp <- "abcdef"
```

I know in advance to which strings I want to apply the regex operation, and hence I want to subset these strings. That is, I don't want to run the regex over all elements in the list, as doing so will return some invalid results (which is not apparent in this simplified example).

I've made a few naive efforts, e.g.:

```
x <- lapply(texts[str_detect(names(texts), "1997")], str_extract, regexp)
> x
$AB1997R.txt
[1] "abcdef"

$DC1997S.txt
[1] "abcdef"
```

which returns a reduced-length list containing just the substrings found.
But the results I want to get are:

```
> x
$AB1997R.txt
[1] "abcdef"

$BG2000S.txt
[1] "mnopqrstuvwxyz"

$MN1999R.txt
[1] "ghijklmnopqrs"

$DC1997S.txt
[1] "abcdef"
```

where the strings not containing the regex pattern are returned in their original state.

I have informed myself about `stringr`, `lapply` and `llply` (in the `plyr` package), but many operations are illustrated using dataframes as examples, not lists, and don't involve regex operations on character strings. I can achieve my goal using a for loop, but I'm trying to get away from that, as is generally advised, and get better at using the apply-class of functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the subset operator `[<-`:

```
x <- texts
is1997 <- str_detect(names(texts), "1997")
x[is1997] <- lapply(texts[is1997], str_extract, regexp)
x
# $AB1997R.txt
# [1] "abcdef"
#
# $BG2000S.txt
# [1] "mnopqrstuvwxyz"
#
# $MN1999R.txt
# [1] "ghijklmnopqrs"
#
# $DC1997S.txt
# [1] "abcdef"
#
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I had tried subsetting on the LHS and RHS, but initially didn't do it the right way & then thought the solution must be complicated. This is ideal.

Comment: What I did wrong is to try to subset with double-brackets. For any other newbies reading this, I figured out that double-brackets returns an object of the same class as the original class of the element, whilst single brackets returns a list object.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `sub`

```
  sub(paste0('.*(', regexp, ').*'), '\\1', texts)
  # AB1997R.txt      BG2000S.txt      MN1999R.txt      DC1997S.txt 
  #  "abcdef" "mnopqrstuvwxyz"  "ghijklmnopqrs"         "abcdef"
```

Also, if you need to match the names of 'texts' with `1997`, we can use `grep`

```
  indx <- grep('1997', names(texts))
  texts[indx] <- sub(paste0('.*(', regexp, ').*'), '\\1', texts[indx])
  as.list(texts)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'm trying to stick with stringr where possible. Also, as the texts are very long, the pattern beginning .* takes a really long time to reach the regex pattern match, perhaps due to backtracking. So that's why I went with str_extract, not str_replace.